# Add class to element inside a-tag

Tags: javascript, html

The following line adds a class to an `<a>`-tag.

```
$("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("active");
```

This works, but I want the class to be added to an `li`-element thats inside the `<a>`-tag.
How would this be done?

Comment: Change `"']"` to `"'] li"`. Although, I'm a little concerned why you're putting a LI inside an A... as that's incorrect HTML, as LIs should only be the immediate child of a UL.

Comment: FYI - An `<a>` should be inside of an `<li>`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to add `li` to the selector as below:

```
 $("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "'] > li").addClass("active");
```

**EDIT:**

There are some suggestions that your HTML should look like

```
<ul>
  <li><a ...>Page1</a></li>
  <li><a ...>Page2</a></li>
  :
</ul>
```

In that case your highlight should be as below:

```
$("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").closest('li').addClass("active");
```

Comment: The OP's request will result in invalid HTML and may not work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox not sure what do you mean?

Comment: LI should only be a direct child of a UL, OL, or MENU element. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li --- Browsers may automatically insert markup to compensate, thus breaking this code.

Comment: read the above moz doc as IE will probably automatically insert markup to compensate and break it

Comment: But how would I wrap a link around a LI?

Comment: @MaxZoom but the whole `li` should be clickable, I dont want to aim with the cursor on the tiny word. I just want to click anywhere on the `li`.

Comment: If that works for you then you are fine. But you can also add the click event listener on `li` elements. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Code below would work for you:

```
$("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "'] li").addClass("active");
```